# Present perfect progressive or simple

Tags: progressive-aspect

> I shall  be  exchanging my house in 2 months, I have bought the plane ticket and planned the stay but  I am a bit worried because I have not  **received** any  further infos for a long time from the person I am exchanging with.

Can I use **I have  not been receiving** instead of **received** because it is ongoing situation and I'd like to emphasize the duration

I don't think so because if I use the progressive it means that before I received infos from the person very often which was not the case. Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. Also, "info" is the contracted form of information which is an uncountable noun.

Comment: But the sentence suggests that the speaker had received "info" from the person he was going to exchange houses with before. The word further denotes that there had been contact in the first place but then it was cut so he didn't receive any further info. So it would give the same meaning, really in addition to emphasizing the duration. I could be wrong btw.